# LIQUIBASE : set number of decimals to a column data type

Tags: liquibase

I want to change the type of a column.
I want a double with 2 decimals max.

I did :

```
<changeSet author="me" id="20170407151802-1">
  <modifyDataType
    columnName="montant_ht"
    newDataType="DOUBLE(10,8)"
    tableName="activite"/>
</changeSet>
```

It doesn't work.
Is there a way to set the precision?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with a DECIMAL type

```
<changeSet author="me" id="20170407151802-1">
  <modifyDataType
    columnName="montant_ht"
    newDataType="DECIMAL(10,2)"
    tableName="activite"/>
</changeSet>
```

Answer (score 0):

the answer depends on your database.

you could try with alter commands to see if your change is supported by your rdbms.

otherwise your can add a new column with this specific type and insert your old data in.